# Determination of a volume.

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, volume

Consider, in the Cartesian plane, the square Q having vertices in the points $(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1)$, and $(0, 1)$.
The sections of a solid with planes orthogonal to $y=0$ are squares having two opposite vertices situated on Q sides. Determine the volume of the solid.

THIS IS MY SOLUTION BUT THE RESULT IS WRONG:

The equation of AB side is: $y = -x + 1$
The equation of BC side is: $y = x - 1$

$$PP' = 2(-x + 1) = -2x + 2$$

is the diagonal of the little squares (the book speaks about OPPOSITE VERTICES)

The side of the little squares measures: ${-2x+2\over \sqrt 2} = -\sqrt2 x + \sqrt 2$

Area = $(- \sqrt 2 x + \sqrt 2)^2 = 2(x^2) - 4x + 2$

$$V = \int_{-1}^1 2x^2-4x+2\,dx = 16/3$$

... but the books says 4/3

Where did I wrong??

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE. You should add some context and/or your attempts if you don't want your topics deleted.

Comment: OK, I have written my solution.  But the book says that the result is 4/3.  Where did I wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the volume is the integral of the cross sectional areas. The two graphs that make the base square are

$$\begin{cases} y_1 = 1-|x| & -1\le x\le 1 \\ y_2=|x|-1 & -1\le x\le 1\end{cases}$$

So that the area of the square orthogonal to it is just the square of the side-length, but all you have is the diagonal length as $y_1-y_2$. However we know that $s\sqrt{2}=d$ is the relation between sides and diagonals, so the cross sectional area is just i.e. $\left({1\over\sqrt{2}}(y_1-y_2)\right)^2$ integrated across $-1\le x\le 1$, which gives us the formula for volume:

> $$V={1\over 2}\int_{-1}^12^2(1-|x|)^2\,dx$$

Doing the algebra out this gives:

$$V=2\left(\int_{-1}^11-2|x|+|x|^2\,dx\right)$$
$$=2\left(\int_{-1}^11\,dx-2\int_{-1}^1 |x|\,dx +\int_{-1}^1 x^2\,dx\right)$$

Now the first integral is easily seen to be $2$, the second is twice the area under $|x|$ which by basic geometry is $2$ because each of the two triangles has area ${1\over 2}$, so the first and second integral cancel one another out, and we are left with

$$\int_{-1}^1 x^2\,dx = {2\over 3}$$

which leaves us with a grand total of $V={4\over 3}$.